# How to find where an application got installed in linux using nodejs

Tags: node.js, linux, path

I installed a server on linux. The installation files gets installed under /opt/AppName/ while the service is under /etc/systemd/system/. I need to get the path of a folder 'cert' which is under /opt/AppName when the server starts. Now the process tries to look under current working directory or the root which obviously fails. How do I get the location where the install files are present?
Have tried:

```
const dircert = 'cert'
const certificateDirWin = path.resolve(`${process.cwd()}`, dircert)
```

and

```
const certificateDir = path.resolve(__dirname, dircert)
```

None of these work.
However if I hardcode

```
const certificateDirLin = path.resolve('/opt/AppName', dircert)
```

it works.
How do I get rid of the harcoded path.